# Is using the expression "pain in the ass" considered rude

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, offensive-language

Is using the expression "pain in the ass" considered rude ?

I'd like to use this expression in a public talk about diffucult outdoor activities, like for instance: "crossing this river was a major pain in the ass" (is actually was).

If yes, what other expression could I use to convey the same idea ?

Comment: Questions like these are a pain in the ass. There, did that feel rude to you?

Comment: ***Pain in the ass and a pain in the butt; a pain in the rear***: 
Fig. a very annoying thing or person. (Crude. Potentially offensive. Use only with discretion. An elaboration of pain. ***Use caution with ass. Butt is less offensive. Rear is euphemistic***.) http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pain+in+the+ass

Comment: @Robusto I'm not a native english speaker, therefore I'm not really sure.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It totally depends on context and audience. But at worst it's a mild epithet.

Comment: @MichaelWalz "pain in the keister"...

Comment: OK, sorry for being snarky. If you are referencing anyone in the room as a pain in the ass, you are being rude. If you're talking about something everyone recognizes as an annoyance, probably not. Use *rear* or *tookus* or some other euphemism for ass if you have to.

Comment: You can use "neck" in place of "ass" if you don't want to offend some of your audience.

Comment: @DanBron the audience is rather "cool".

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they are cool or hot. You can just use non-offensive word. "Pain in the ass" doesn't sound offensive to me but it might to someone, maybe your boss. :)

Comment: "Ass" is a (very mild) profanity, and should not generally be used in church (except when describing a beast of burden).  "Butt", "rear", and "neck" are alternatives, in order of descending offensiveness.  And the idiom "a pain in the X" (where X can be any of the above words and more) is informal, and should be avoided in any formal setting (eg, formal writing and formal lectures).  Plus, of course, it can be offensive if used to describe someone within earshot (but less so when used to describe, say, Windows).

Comment: Considered by whom? Depends whom you are talking to - what **they** consider rude. The question should be closed as unclear (no context) or primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The a-word can sound rude and inappropriate, depending on the audience.

A more appropriate expression could be **a pain in the neck** (edit: just noticed that Rathony suggested this in comments already):

> something or someone that causes trouble; a source of unhappiness

([WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=pain%20in%20the%20neck&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=0))

You can also simply say crossing the river was a major *ordeal* or *trial*.

Comment: Pain in the neck: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pain+in+the+neck

Comment: Josh, my point is, if one can't use "pain in the ass", one can use "pain in the neck" as a euphemism, a replacement for the former. I think that's the way it would be understood by the audience. See http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/pain - here they are interchangeable.